# Columns with equal height and background color overflowing container

Tags: css

I want to achieve this:
[image]

or

[image]

Preferably in css only.

I have searched around and read this article http://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-equal-height-columns/. However it does not really tackle the background colors overflowing the container issue.

Comment: This image is actually a better illustration: http://i.imgur.com/3XYHwBk.png

Comment: Overflowing what container? You need to at least show us some code

Comment: can you post some sample code in [Jsfiddle](http://http://jsfiddle.net/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have a div that is trapped inside of a parent container it is going to be difficult to get it to overflow horizontally. If you can get the div that you want to overflow outside of that container it would be best.

If not, one way you can achieve this effect is using the :before and :after on the divs that you want to overflow. Basically you are giving them the same height and background-color and then position them to the right and left of the main div.

```
.overflowing-div { position: relative; }
.overflowing-div:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0;
    margin-left: -100%;
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%; /* or fixed height if you know the height of the div you want to extend */
    background-color: #ccc; /* same color as .overflowing-div */
}
```

and the same thing for the :after, just using right and margin-right

Comment: dont do that @MattCoughlin. It will make the :before and :after elements not show at all which completely defeats the purpose. overflow: hidden could be added to the outermost containing element of the page to prevent horizontal scroll bars, but that has to be based on the set up of the site.

Comment: So far I get this: http://jsfiddle.net/tolborg/mmMpH/ . However, as you can see I have used js to size the content div. The :before and :after elements have height 100%, but this is no good if the content div isnt clearfixing the floated columns. However, if I use clearfix I overflow hidden. Can it be done without js at all?

Comment: this can, and should be done without js. A lot of issues here, but here's the main ones: the :before and :after that are for the bg-color should be on the actual div that has that bg-color. in this case use the :before of .content-main and the :after of .content-aside. the clearfix should be applied to the container div, which in this case is .content.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. But, how would you give the two columns equal heights?